# Snakemake: error when using split command?

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm getting an error when I use the Unix `split` command in the shell part of my Snakemake rule:

```
rule split:
    input:
            "test_file.txt"
    output:
            directory("split_test_file")
    shell:
            '''
            mkdir {output}
            split -1 3 {input} split_
            mv split_* {output}
            '''
```

This is the error:

```
Error in rule split:
jobid: 0
output: split_test_file
shell:
    
    mkdir split_test_file
    split -1 3 test_file.txt split_
    mv split_* split_test_file
    
    (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)
```

I think the error occurs in the `mv split_* split_test_file` line because when I run only the first 2 lines there is no error. I can't seem to find why I can't move all the files that resulted from splitting `test_file.txt` into the output directory? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is a typo in `split` command, where `-1` needs to be letter `-l`.
2. Your `mv` command would result in error `mv: cannot move ‘split_test_file’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘split_test_file/split_test_file’`. Both the files to be moved and the destination directory begin with same string `split_`, which leads to this error. Modifying either of them would fix this issue.